# From HTML Coded Text to readable text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like clearly display some text coded in html, at the moment I use this script.

Replace method works but I cannot display the text in a readable format in my case

> "Hello!"

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

HTML :

```
   <span class="sp">test</span>
```

JS :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('span.sp').each(function(i) {
            var text = $(this).text();
            var name = text.replace("test", "&#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#33;");
            $(this).text(name);
        });
    });
```

Comment: So you'd like to remove the html tags?

Comment: I need replace the word "test" with "&#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#33;" but I need the result DECODED in my final render (html).. any idea? thanks!

Comment: May I ask what's the purpose of this? I mean, why encoding text like that?

Comment: Entry Level Search Engine obfuscation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.sp').each(function(i) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var name = text.replace("test", "&#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#33;");
            $(this).html(name);  //added
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: unescape() function in Javascript would indeed work also.. so you can chose ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the unescape() function in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `charCodeAt()` function:

```
var s = "hello!";
var se = "";

for (var x=0; x<s.length; x++){
    se = se + "&#" + s.charCodeAt(x)+";";
}

alert(se);
```